# Automating ArcGIS share service with Python?

Tags: arcpy, map-service

Right now i am sharing a map service in ArcGIS by following these steps.

File --> Share as --> Service --> then click on overwrite an existing service --> select appropriate map --> Click on Analyse  --> Publish service.

Is it possible to do all this task with a small python code?

Answer (score 1):

I searched for "arcpy publish map service" and found [Publishing a map service with Python](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.2/index.html#//00sq000000nw000000):

> You can automate map service publishing in a Python script. To do
>   this, you need to call the following sequence of functions from the
>   arcpy.mapping module and tools from the Server toolbox.

Comment: Looks like it's the same content, but just in case it changes, here's the link to the 10.3 version of the linked documentation: http://server.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/publish-services/windows/publishing-a-map-service-with-python.htm

Comment: frankly all existing sample codes over the web are not smart enough, you always need to enter the the mxd name! I am looking forward a code that you can enter only the path of the folder that contains all of my mxd's (around 80 mxd) then it will do the job of publishing and print the errors (  not published mxd) to a text file. there should be a way to do a loop inside theses codes to automate the work and skip the errors

Comment: @Ahmadsaleh it isn't really an arcpy function to find and loop through files - that is thoroughly covered in the native Python functionality (e.g. the `os` module) and is fairly trivial - so it's not included in GIS examples. Do a [search on StackOverflow for file looping](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=python+loop+through+all+files+in+folder) and plug the 2 together

Comment: Does the solution support publishing to ArcGIS Online?

Comment: @alextc I've not tried it